# TypeOrm create OneToOne row

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Basic postgres+typeorm+nestjs question (that I somehow can´t find a solid answer to):
I have three example tables: *customers*, *products*, and *orders*. For this example *orders* only has two columns of *product* and *column* as oneToOne relations.

Now I want to do the basic step of creating an order. I have the customer id and the product id. Can`t I just put them in the corresponding columns? Do I really have to fetch the customer and product first?

```
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Order)
    private readonly orderRepository: Repository<Order>,
    @InjectRepository(Customer)
    private readonly customerRepository: Repository<Customer>,
    @InjectRepository(Product)
    private readonly productRepository: Repository<Product>,
  ) {}

  async newOrder(order: OrderDto) {
    const [customer, product] = await Promise.all([
      this.customerRepository.findOneBy({
        id: order.customer,
      }),
      this.productRepository.findOneBy({
        id: order.product,
      }),
    ]);

    const newOrder = this.orderRepository.create({
      customer,
      product,
    });
    return this.orderRepository.save(newOrder);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this example orders only has two columns of product and column as oneToOne relations

I believe what you're trying to say is that each record in the `orders` has one linked record in `customers` and one linked record in `products`.

**TLDR**: You don't need to query either the `customers` or the `products` tables.

---

Make your `Order` entity class like the below and manually provide the foreign key columns. If you don't, TypeOrm will do this for you but the column names might be `customer_id`, and `product_id`.

```js
@Entity('orders')
class Order {
  // Here provide the type based on `id` column in `Customer` entity.
  @Column({ type: 'varchar'})
  customerId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Customer)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'customerId' })
  customer: Customer;

  // Here provide the type based on `id` column in `Product` entity.
  @Column({ type: 'varchar'})
  productId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Product)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'productId' })
  product: Product;
}
```

Then in your service class, you can do this:

```js
@Injectable()
export class OrderService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Order)
    private readonly orderRepository: Repository<Order>,
  ) {}

  async newOrder(order: OrderDto) {
    const newOrder = this.orderRepository.create({
      customerId: order.customer,
      productId: order.product,
    });
    return this.orderRepository.save(newOrder);
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, thats exactly what i was looking for. The typeOrm docs suggest that the IDs are created via the  Decorators (https://typeorm.io/one-to-one-relations). Thanks!